# Getting a value from a textbox in javascript with Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, textbox

I have a problem with a Macro in Excel, I want to return the value of an "input type="text"" in a javascript webpage, but the value isn't specified in the code (value=""), and it never changes, even when the webpage shows a text in the textbox (The webpage "prints" a text in this textbox, it's not an input by the user).

```
Using "IE.Document.getElementById("lat_txt_velmaxima").Value", returns Null.
```

The code on the page is:

```
class="campo txt_velmaxima"> <label for="lat_txt_velmaxima">Velocidade máxima:</label> 

<input type="text" name="lat_txt_velmaxima" id="lat_txt_velmaxima"
disabled="disabled" value="" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you just need to grab the value of that readonly text input.

If that's the case, the right way to query the DOM API through JavaScript is the following:

```
document.getElementById('lat_txt_velmaxima').value;
```

Note the lowercase d in `document`, and lowercase v in `value`.

Comment: There is no value in the HTML code, I can not get the value of it by document.getElementById ('lat_txt_velmaxima'). I need to copy the direct value of the page, because I can not bring the value by reading the HTML code.
But thank you for the answer.

Note: The code is for VBA in excel.
Sample codes I've tried:
 [Range ("P" & Counter) .Value = IE.document.getElementsByTagName ("lat_txt_velmaxima")]

 Range ("P1"). Value = IE.document.getElementsByTagName ("lat_txt_velmaxima")

[ Range ("P1"). Value = IE.document.getElementById ("lat_txt_velmaxima")]

Comment: @CarlosGuardado: The HTML code you've added above, where there is no value for the input: did you get that from the source code of the page, or by inspecting the DOM with your browser's developer tools? If you got it from the source, it's possible that the value is being added to it dynamically on the front end, and will be there for you to query. If you got it by inspecting the DOM, then there really is no value there for you to query. The 'direct value of the page' is the DOM.

Comment: Yeah, I've got it from the source code, and it is added dynamically, in that case, could you provide an example code that can execute this task, or the steps for me to follow?